# Using a custom Vertical SeekBar, thumb highlight does not rotate with the bar

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using a custom Vertical Seekbar and everything works great, except for the Thumb highlight.

[image]

As I scroll the left seekbar up and down, the thumb highlight continues to scroll left to right at the top of the screen as if the seekbar is still horizontal. My custom vertical seekbar is as follows:

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

protected OnSeekBarChangeListener changeListener;

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) {
    super.setProgress(progress);
    onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
}

@Override public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener mListener)
{
    this.changeListener = mListener;
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(),0);

    super.onDraw(c);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
            if (changeListener != null)
                changeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
            setSelected(true);
            setPressed(true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (changeListener != null)
                changeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
            setSelected(false);
            setPressed(false);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int i=getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
            setProgress(i);
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
            if (changeListener != null)
                changeListener.onProgressChanged(this, i, true);
            setPressed(true);
            setSelected(true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

I can eliminate the highlight entirely by removing

```
setSelected(true);
setPressed(true);
```

But ideally I want to keep the standard design pattern and have the highlight follow where the thumb is. Is there anyway to access the location and position of the highlight so I can rotate that as well?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and came across this similar post for an answer: 
[Android SeekBar custom rectangle thumb visual bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085187/android-seekbar-custom-rectangle-thumb-visual-bug)

Set the Background to null. I added "setBackground(null);" to the constructor of my extended SeekBar class, but the suggested solution does this in the activity.xml file under the "SeekBar" section.

Comment: This works if you are trying to eliminate the thumb highlight altogether, but what i want is to keep the thumb highlight so as to keep the design pattern true to android default, The problem is that the highlight stays in the horizontal plane, separate from the now vertical seekbar. I guess the only solution would be to create a custom thumb highlight as well and make it match the standard